# how to get and use the current url after the page is finiahed loading in android WebView

Tags: java, android

im trying to use the returned url after mypage finishes loading and comparing it with another url which is the same.

here is my code:

```
String success ="https://example.com/success";

public void onPageFinished(WebView webv, String url){
    if(success==url){
        doFunction1();
    }else{
        doFunction2();
    }           
}
```

it seems like the two Links are not the same then only `doFunction2()` is called.

(The page redirects to the success page and I just wanna check if the page really redirected or not)

Comment: log the values and see whether they match

Comment: sometimes the pages add some query parameters or if its SPA then it ll change the path

Comment: To compare strings you need to use equals not ==

Comment: @AmrDeveloper i used ```matches```. it works now thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have set your WebViewClient.If not then you can do like below,
You can use this method to achieve what you want

```
   webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

String success ="https://example.com/success";


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String currentUrlLink  = request.getUrl().toString();

           if(success.equals(currentUrlLink)){
                    doFunction1();
        }else{
            doFunction2();
        }     
            return false;
        }
    }
```

here currentUrlLink is the string where it gets the webView's current URL. and using `.equals()` you can match the `success` string with the current URL.